# Coffeescript Unexpected Newline

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

```
#Sprite Objects
  sprites =
    1:
      name: "Truffle Faerie"
      location: "sprite.jpg"
      height: "250"
      width: "100"
      placeSprite:()-> 
        elem = document.createElement("img")
        elem.setAttribute("src", spites[1].location)
        elem.setAttribute("height", sprites[1].height)
        elem.setAttribute("width", sprites[1].width)
        document.getElementById("viewport").appendChild(elem)
```

Why in god's name is this giving me an "Unexpected Newline Error" when I try to compile this? Am I not allowed to use separate lines on an object method?

This is the first huge hicup i've had with this language, and it's enough to make me want to rip out my hair. Am I just missing something tiny here?

Notepad++ is my text editor. Koala is my compiler.

Comment: Does the error message give you a line number?

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately

Comment: "Try CoffeeScript" at coffeescript.org says it is okay. I guess you'll have to start removing one line at a time until the error goes away and then see what was strange about the last line you removed.

Answer (score 2):

Okay so after hours and hours I figured out what the issue was. For anyone else having this problem, it's coffeescript not playing well with notepad++. My code was copied from Codepen.io to a notepad++ file and that created all sorts of hell when I went to edit it.

My fix was to download a zip file of my codepen, import the coffeescript file in notepad++ and then use only spaces, never tabs!

Of those most unsatisfying things to fix, this ranked at the top.

Answer (score 0):

i think , maybe there is a little wrong just like mine.

```coffee
 sprites =
    1: # here should be only 1, not [1:], the [:]is error. my code with same error, i find it for long time, maybe can save other people 's time.
      name: "Truffle Faerie"
      location: "sprite.jpg"
      height: "250"
```